# How to decrement numbers inside a string

Tags: ruby

I have a string of integers that can be separated by a comma, hyphen or both. e.g.

```
str = '3,7-17,21'
```

I need to take those numbers and reduce them by 1 without losing their position in that string.

When I split, I lose commas and hyphens so their positions change.

Is there a nice way to turn my string into `2,6-16,20`?

I started on the following but just ended up in a rabbit hole:

```
def reduce_hours(hours)
  hours
    .enum_for(:scan, /\d+/)
    .map { Regexp.last_match(0) }
    .map(&:to_i)
    .map { |hour| hour - 1 }
    .then { hours }
end

hours = '3,7-17,21'
```

It just returns the original string.  When I debug, it does match the numbers individually and reduce them by 1.  It just doesn't return those changes to the original string.  Am I close with that snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enum_for(:scan, ...)`, `Regexp.last_match(0)`, `then` – you're overthinking it.

You can just use [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#gsub-method) to replace each numeric substring by its predecessor:

```
str = '3,7-17,21'

str.gsub(/\d+/) { |hour| hour.to_i - 1 }
#=> "2,6-16,20"
```

The `to_i` round trip is needed, because strings can't be decremented directly.

The opposite direction is even easier: (via [`String#succ`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#succ-method))

```
"2,6-16,20".gsub(/\d+/, &:succ)
#=> "3,7-17,21"
```

Comment: Of all my years in Ruby, I never thought to pass in a block to gsub like that

Comment: Watch out for `0` as it will turn into `-1`. You might want `0` → `23` instead.

Comment: I've added a clause for `if hour.to_i.positive?`

Comment: If negative integers are permitted perhaps use `rgx = /(?:(?<!\d)\-)?\d+/`. Then `"2,6-16,20".gsub(rgx) { |s| s.to_i.succ } #=> "3,7-17,21"`, `"-2,-16--6,20".gsub(rgx) { |s| s.to_i.succ } #=> "-1,-15--5,21"`, `"-2,-16 - -6,20".gsub(rgx) { |s| s.to_i.succ } #=> "-1,-15 - -5,21"`. Unfortunately (here), `"-5".succ #=> "-6"`, not `#=> "-4"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def process_comma(str)
  str.split(',').map do |sub_str|
    sub_str.include?('-') ? process_hiphen(sub_str) : (sub_str.to_i - 1).to_s
  end.join(',')
end

def process_hiphen(str)
  str.split('-').map do |sub_str|
    (sub_str.to_i - 1).to_s
  end.join('-')
end


str = '3,7-17,21'
process_comma(str)    # "2,6-16,20"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go by each possible delimiter.

```rb
hours = '3,7-17,21'

def reduce_hours(hours)
  hours
    .split('-')
    .map { |comma_seperated_strings|
      comma_seperated_strings
        .split(',')
        .map(&:to_i)
        .map{|x| x-1}
        .map(&:to_s)
        .join(',')
    }
    .join('-')
end

puts reduce_hours(hours)
```